# Internal architecture of in memory data base

Tags: sqlite, in-memory-database

I'm using **SQLite** open-source database in my embedded system.
I have set below PRAGMA

```
qDb.exec("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF");
qDb.exec("PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY");
```

PRAGMA is for In-Memory working.
Without this flag database performance is slow but after this PRAGMA performance improvement is really noticeable.

so I decide to use an in-memory database for my embedded application.
I know that the in-memory database whole dataset in RAM whereas in the traditional database whole database in DISK.  **So RAM operation is faster then DISK operation.**

My question

1. I want to understand when data is written in the main memory?
   (`Let's say I have written 100 rows in table A. After which time it is safe to the power of the device`)
2. How to minimize data loss risk in an in-memory database.
   (`Is it technically possible`)

Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You expect an in memory database to persist across power cycles?

Comment: @Shawn I'm not expecting an in-memory database persist across power cycles. In my system, I continuously write logs in one table. I want to find out that if my system is power off how many rows of data I lose due to the in-memory DB configuration. And Let's say I lose 5-rows data is there any method to reduce this data loss Thank You for your time!!

Comment: If you're using normal RAM, you'd lose everything. If you want persistence, use a file-backed database.

Comment: @Shawn Lets consider one scenario `I have an in-memory database configuration, Then I insert 500 rows in one table, Then I power off the device.`  Assuming Result 1: All inserted 500 rows I lost in DB due to sudden power off as per your suggestion           
(Q.) When it is safe to power off the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has a **checkpoint** that is managed data to write data in the main memory.

An **automatic checkpoint** is taken when the transaction log file becomes bigger than X GB since the last checkpoint. And after that size of the transaction log data write-in to main memory from RAM.

Data also write in the main memory when the last database connection on a database file closes.